# Rellenar un reporte desde un datatable c# crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Estoy haciendo una aplicación windows forms, en la cual hago una consulta a mi base de datos en access, el resultado de esta consulta me genera un datatable, quiero saber como puedo recorrerlo y rellenar el report (.rpt) sin tener que crear la conexión dentro de el, ya que le paso los valores por el datatable.

Si quiero mostrar por ejemplo el informe de un único cliente, me funciona bien de la siguiente manera (en el informe rpt he creado un campo de parametro llamado txtNombreCli, que recoge el valor de oCliente.Nombre:

```
oCliente = Manejador_Clientes.SacarDatosTabla("Clientes", frmClientes.iIdCliente);
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
string path = "../../crClientes.rpt";
cryRpt.Load(path);
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("txtNombreCli", oCliente.sNombre);
cRVClientes1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer, es listar de la tabla clientes todos los clientes, he probado enlazando desde el rpt la base de datos y me funciona bien, pero lo quiero hacer pasando los datos por el datatable tal que así:

```
dtBusqueda = Manejador_Clientes.Datos_Clientes(); // Me devuelve un datatable con todos los datos de los clientes (select * from clientes)
ReportDocument Report = new ReportDocument();
Report.Load("../../crCliente.rpt");
Report.SetDataSource(dtBusqueda);
cRVClientes2.ReportSource = Report;
```

El caso es que así, en el rpt no puedo o no se recoger los datos para que me muestre todos los clientes, ya digo que enlazando el rpt con la base de datos directamente si que me funciona.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar dataset para  datatable.

```html
    public static DsReporte CargarArticulos()
{
    DsReporte ds = new DsReporte();
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("tu  cadena de conexion")
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Articulo";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "Articulo");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

llenas el reporte asi

```html
   DsReporte datos = CargarArticulos();
 
    CrpReporte report = new CrpReporte();
    report.SetDataSource(datos);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

Si queres filtras datos aqui explico como hacerlo
[FILTRAR DATOS DE REPORTE - CRYSTAL REPORT](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2013/01/filtrar-datos-de-reporte-crystal-report.html)

Comment: Gracias Cristian por tu ayuda, así como comentas funciona, pero lo ideal para mí sería poder hacerlo sin pasar por un DataSet, ya que tendría que agregarlo al proyecto (Agregar -> Nuevo Elemento -> Data -> Conjunto de Datos -> DataSet1.xsd ). ¿Se podría hacer como te digo ? Es decir, rellenar todo el reporte con el datatable sin pasar por el elemento de proyecto DataSet.

Comment: Solucionado como me habías comentado, gracias!